# filtering a dataframe with uuids returns an empty result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data frame:

df:

| id | hint |
| --- | --- |
| 29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab | None |
| 61afc910-3918-11ea-b078-93fcef773138 | Yes |

and I want to find the first row that has this id = 29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab

when I run this code:

`df[df['id'] == '29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab']`

return empty!!! and the type of this id is "object"

but I really have this id!!

how can I find it?

Comment: Your code and logic look correct.  Are you certain that this problem is reproducible?

Comment: double check for spaces and case: `df[df['id'].str.strip().str.lower() == '29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab']`

Comment: Yes! I'm facing this problem now!

Comment: @mozway : I got this error: "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: you must provide a reproducible input then, your question cannot be answered without it

Comment: @mozway what do you mean by reproducible input? I already write two real rows from my data

Comment: Well, it's not reproducible. If I try your current example it works well. Provide a DataFrame constructor or dictionary. What is the output of `df.to_dict('list')`?

Comment: @mozway here is it:

Comment: {'id': [UUID('29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab'),
  UUID('61afc910-3918-11ea-b078-93fcef773138'),
  UUID('7a14da70-56e4-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab'),
  UUID('8cc57910-e053-11e9-ad24-9f59cfcfdf73'),
  UUID('4f5e8340-323d-11eb-bf06-b3c903102c38')],
 'hint': [None,
  UUID('95a3cc20-4f18-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab'),
  UUID('c0c63810-3f6a-11e9-9d94-4bd700ec821f'),
  None,
  None]}

Comment: Here is your answer, you don't have strings but UUIDs ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code didn't work because you have [UUIDs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html), not strings, you first need to convert to string:

```
df[df['id'].astype(str).eq('29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab')]
```

Output:

```
                                     id  hint
0  29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab  None
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use property DataFrame.loc[source], [read here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
 df.loc[df['id'] == '29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab']
```

Comment: This is not the issue, boolean indexing works with both `[]` and `.loc[]`

Comment: it returns empty result

Answer (score 1):

1 more work arond

so instead of converting `"id"` column to `str` you can do

```
from uuid import UUID

df[df['id'].eq(UUID('29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab'))]
```

**output:**

```
                                     id  hint
0  29c45630-7d41-11e9-8ea2-9f2bfe5760ab  None
```