# Select row in dataframe containing a specific UUID

Tags: python, pandas, uuid

I have a dataframe, one column of which holds a UUID:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import uuid

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    columns=['a', 'b', 'c']
)

df['d'] = np.NaN
df['d'] = df['d'].apply(
    lambda x: uuid.uuid4()
)
```

Preview:

```
df

-------     a   b   c   d
------- 0   1   2   3   31abc2af-117d-4fe8-b43f-e68fa429187f
------- 1   4   5   6   f63b36c8-bb4e-4148-ace9-a89fa117e15c
```

I now want to select rows based on a UUID. But the following returns an empty set of rows:

```
df.loc[
    df['d'] == '31abc2af-117d-4fe8-b43f-e68fa429187f'
]
```

How do I select rows using UUID as the match criteria?

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75185990/filtering-a-dataframe-with-uuids-returns-an-empty-result) (not sure if this is a duplicate)

Comment: @mozway Thanks - I hadn't come across that when I searched. Have okayed the question being marked as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Pandas shows the column to be of `object` type, but I did notice that pulling the value for a specific row revealed that pandas was holding the identifier as a UUID rather than simply as a string:

```
df.iloc[0]['d']

------- UUID('31abc2af-117d-4fe8-b43f-e68fa429187f')
```

I couldn't find an answer to this, but after trying various things I worked out that the following is needed:

```
df.loc[
    df['d'] == uuid.UUID('31abc2af-117d-4fe8-b43f-e68fa429187f')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you found a solution to you problem. Another solution would be to convert the column values to strings:

`df.loc[df['d'].astype(str) == '31abc2af-117d-4fe8-b43f-e68fa429187f']`